# CORE 2 MVC Ajax redirect to display a view

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an application that uses the jQuery Datatable and I want to click on a row, pick up the id, and then bring up a view that allows for editing of that view and updating the underlying database.
Ajax gets me to the controller-action that for the edit view but I can't get the view itself to display.  Instead, the controller action just returns to ajax.  I've tried numerous tactics with no joy.  Here is a simple example based upon a standard CORE template:

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', 'button.number', function () {
            alert($(this).val());
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("About", "Home")'
            });
        });
    </script>
}

<h3>Home Page</h3>
<div>
    <button href="#" type="button" class="number" id="one" value="1">1</button>
    <button href="#" type="button" class="number" id="two" value="2">2</button>
</div>
```

Running the debugger shows that About action is called OK but the view isn't rendered - it just returns to ajax.  I've tried all sorts of redirection but any "return" just goes back to ajax.

Is there away around this or perhaps a better way to get from the JS to the controller-action?  Thanks

EDIT:
Batuhan gets the credit for his solution but I'm re-posting it to clean up a little syntax and add the parameter passing that was my initial goal.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.number', function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            alert(id);
            $.ajax
                ({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("About", "Home")',
                }).success(function (result) {
                    window.location.href = '/home/about/' + id;
                });
        });
```

And here is Home Controller for the About Action:

```js
public IActionResult About(int id)
        {
            string parm2 = id.ToString();
            ViewBag.msg = parm2;
            return View();
        }
```

And the About page:

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
}
<p>
    <h1> @ViewBag.msg </h1>
</p>
```

All works as initially hoped for!

Comment: You call the server method (I assume its not really `About()`?)  but you never do anything with the partial view it returns- to add it to the DOM you need to do that in the `success` callback - `success: function(response) { $(someElement).html(response); }`

Comment: But it sounds like you really want to redirect to a new view, in which case do not use ajax - the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page (ajax calls cannot redirect)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, Yes, I want to redirect to a new view.  My little example starts on the Index page and I'm trying to redirect to the About page (standard template).  I didn't understand this basic concept of ajax whereby it can't redirect - but I certainly do now!  I gave up on this approach and put the selected id from the Data Table row (in my actual project) into an input field and then used a button to post to a new Controller-Action.  This works fine even if the approach is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Whats wrong with using `@Html.ActionLink()` to generate a `<a>` which redirects

Comment: Stephen: in my actual project I need to use JS to extract a value from the Datatable row selected by the user.  So, what I've done now is similar to your ActionLink suggestion: I use JS to get the value and then put it in an HTML field so I can use an razor command to redirect.  I don't think there is a way to use a razor command inside of  JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).on('click', 'button.number', function () {
            alert($(this).val());
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("About", "Home")'
            }).success: function(result){
       ///this line 
window.href='redirect url';

    }});;
        });
```

this is a solution cause you cant redirect from ajax call. it returns The view in html form So if you want to postback you needto use window.href="url";